# Regarding WebDriver Sampler and Config/Listener Folder Path

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

While trying to write Webdriver sampler with Config/listener element ,I have below issue ,Could any team assist me for the same?
1:- In config /listener element/webdriver browser setup file , if we want to enter some value from external resource (' or if we want to save summary report in PC, Is there any procedure to give unique path that can be run in any workstation /pc/ any directory after giving file name only because  if we execute in other station or move file in other directory, everytime we need to change file location?Could you please guide me for the same?

2. While writing webdriver sampler request,I am able to execute script but i am getting below error in log viewer window and also wanted to break functionality as very small unit label for one webdriver sampler request{launch site/login successfully,validate record, logout} so after searching on google , i used sub sample start or samplestart function multiple time , but i am not getting label name in view tree listener result after setting one jmeter property. Could you please guide me for the same?

3:- Could we run three thread group at same time(all three thread run at same time) or some interval (first and sec run on same time but third start after 10 minute)

Thanks you for giving valuable time in advance?[image]
[image: r]

[image]
Thanks Amit

Answer (score 0):

1. You can give only the filename and JMeter will look for the CSV file and write results file into JMeter's "bin" folder (or the place where you launched JMeter from). You can also use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to parameterize the file name or even path, for example if you do set your CSV Data Set Config like:

   ```
   ${__P(testdata,TestData.csv)}
   ```

   you will be able to [override the path using -J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jtestdata=/path/to/somefile.csv
   ```

   If you don't provide the property, default value of `TestData.csv` will be used. More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
2. You're getting this "Invalid call sequence" error because you have duplicate `WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()` function call, just remove one of them and that would be it.
3. Add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the first request or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler at the beginning of the Thread Group 3 and configure them to sleep for `600000` milliseconds.